# Context Initialization Parameters for Managed Bean

Tags: jsf-2, el, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, adfc-config

## Background

A managed bean must have parameters configured through its web.xml file. The web.xml file defines context initialization parameters that are configured in JDeveloper (11.1.2.3) as follows:

[image]

The source for the definition of `reporting.server.protocol` follows:

```
  <context-param>
    <description>Defines the data transport mechanism to ret...</description>
    <param-name>reporting.server.protocol</param-name>
    <param-value>http</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

The bean exposes public accessor methods for `reportServerProtocol`.

The source for the bean resembles:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class OracleReportBean extends ReportBean {

  @ManagedProperty("#{initParam['reporting.server.protocol']}")
  private String reportServerProtocol = URLReportImpl.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL;

  // ...
}
```

## Problem

I would like to initialize the bean using context initialization parameters, rather than through [FacesContext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4533483/59087). In `adfc-config.xml` (note: not `faces-confg.xml`), some examples show references to `initParam`:

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>reportBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>ca.corp.report.view.OracleReportBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
    <property-name>reportServerProtocol</property-name>
    <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
    <value>#{initParam['reporting.server.protocol']}</value>
  </managed-property>
...
</managed-bean>
```

The key line being the value element `#{initParam['reporting.server.protocol']}`. However, JDeveloper shows the line as being incorrect. That is, the `initParam` context is not available within `adfc-confing.xml`.

The error is: "EL token `initParam` is unknown."

## Question

Using an [EL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language), how can the context initialization parameters be used to configure a managed bean, declaratively within ADFc?

## Related Links

- [How to inject entire managed bean via @ManagedProperty annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165567/how-to-inject-entire-managed-bean-via-managedproperty-annotation)
- http://balusc.blogspot.ca/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/43-remote-task-flow-169185.pdf
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/web.1111/b31974/taskflows_activities.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bug in JDeveloper causes errors to be displayed:

[image: JDeveloper Error]

However, even though the IDE displays an error, the code executes as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In the ui layer you could try something like this :

```
<c:set target="${BeanName}" property="PropertyName" value="${true}"/>
```